# How to create a b2body using box2d that is continuously moving left and right and doesn't fall down when player jumps on to it?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, game-physics

I am working on a platformer game using cocos2d with box2d in which i have ground body that must continuously move to left and right, but doesn't fall when player jumps onto it. I am not able to do so, my body falls when player jump onto it. Provide me some link or code to do so.

[image]

Comment: This is a good situation to use a kinematic body.

Comment: but kinematic body doesn't collide with static bodies.

Comment: Moving the kinematic body back and forward from one side of the pit to the other does not require collision with static bodies.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the best solution is to move the sprite for the platform, not the platform itsef.

Instead of creating a small platform for the jumping, create a rectangle that extends across the entire pit.

Only move the sprite over the region that you want the player to jump on to (i.e. move it left and right so the player knows the "safe" area to jump).

Use the b2ContactListener to detect the collision between the rectangle and the player.  If they are in contact and the player is over the moving sprite, then don't do anything different.

If they are in contact and the player is *NOT* over the moving sprite, disable the collisions response in the PreSolve event of the b2Contact listener and for the entire time the player is in contact with it.  The player should fall through to the pit below.

You could also use a sensor body for the moving platform to give you a better "contact mechanism" than just the sprite.  So if the player is in contact with the "platform sensor" and the "rectangle across the pit", don't do anything in the PreSolve event.  Otherwise, if they are *only* in contact with the "rectangle across the pit", let them drop through it.

Does this work?

Comment: I am not able to get u, what u suggesting is too complex.. is there any way with kinematic bodies.